# TinyMCE add class to img tag

Tags: php, javascript, css, tinymce, wysiwyg

I am using TinyMCE editor as a stand alone editor in my CMS.

The site, by default puts a curved border around any image tags within the cms div ID.

I need to have the option, within the CMS to bypass by adding a `class="no-style"` on the rare occasion a image being added to a page shouldn't have the CSS border. However I do not see any way to do this with TinyMCE..

All I see is a way to enter style tags, but this won't work since the code I am using in CSS to make the borders is this:

```
-webkit-border-radius: 5px; -moz-border-radius: 5px; border-radius: 5px; -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(0,0,0,.2); -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(0,0,0,.2); box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(0,0,0,.2); behavior: url(js/PIE.htc);
```

so to take all those to 0px everytime I need to do a image with no border is time consuming and not to mention too much for the average person.

So on this page: http://d.pr/i/wslc

Is there a way to have a dropdown or a text box where someone can type in "just like style" a class name, such as no-style which would be in the style.css taking those properties I have above to zero?

Thanks!

Answer (score 21):

You need to define a list of predefined classes according to https://www.tinymce.com/docs/plugins/image/#image_class_list

Adding the following to `tinymce.init`

```
image_class_list: [
    {title: 'None', value: ''},
    {title: 'Lightbox', value: 'lightbox'},
]
```

Outputs

[image: tinymce class list]

Comment: Nice solution. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

TinyMCE has support for this.

When adding a new image (`Insert/Add Image`-popup), click the tab that says `Appearance`. In the dropdown that says `Class`, chose `Value` and enter `no-style`. I think you can customize TinyMCE to support your own classes (ie, it is already listed), but I am not sure how you can do that. Looking at the documentation should help, if you do not want to type it in manually each time.

Edit: Ah, I did not look at the picture before I answered. It looks like you have an outdated version of TinyMCE. On the webpage the dropdown described above is available: [Official site](http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/3_x/full.php).

Superedit: If you already have the last version, take a look at the plugins you are loading. Take a look at the source from the official site and compare it to your own.

Answer (score -3):

Try put your code on html mode in tinyMCE.